# Connect a combox with a slider

Tags: qt, slider, qwt, qcombobox

I'm trying to connect a qcombobox with a qwtslider, and I have two options on the combox, mm and pixel. I want to make the scale change to pixels or mms when I choose that option. I've created some functions to work as slots and those are:

```
void planevolume::mm()
{
      ui->Slider->setRange(xmin, xmax/(256/3), 1.0/(256/3));
      ui->Slider->setScale(xmin, (xmax+1)/(256/3), ((xmax+1)/16)/(256/3));
      connect(ui->Slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), ui->lcdNumber, SLOT(display(double)));
}

void planevolume::pixel()
{
      ui->Slider->setRange(xmin, xmax, 1.0);
      ui->Slider->setScale(xmin, xmax+1, (xmax+1)/16);
      connect(ui->Slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), ui->lcdNumber, SLOT(display(double)));
}
```

and i thought i could connect them using a signal from the connect box. my connect box is this:

```
  ui->comboBox->insertItem( 1, QString("pixel"));
  ui->comboBox->insertItem( 2, QString("mm"));
```

And them creating a slot to choose:

```
void planevolume::currentIndexPixel()
{
    ui->comboBox->currentIndex(1);
}

void planevolume::currentIndexMM()
{
    ui->comboBox->currentIndex(2);
}
```

them connecting it like this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(currentIndexPixel()),ui->Slider, SLOT(pixel()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(currentIndexMM()),ui->Slider, SLOT(mm()));
```

but I'm getting the error like this, and I'm not sure what am I doing wrong:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘QComboBox::currentIndex(int)’
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qcombobox.h:184: note: candidates are: int QComboBox::currentIndex() const
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to use `setCurrentIndex()` rather than `currentIndex()` in your `currentIndexPixel` and `currentIndexMM` functions

Comment: like that i get
 multiple definition of `planevolume::currentIndexPixel()' and  multiple definition of `planevolume::currentIndexMM()'

Comment: I tried with void activated(int index) and void currentIndexChanged(int index) but i got that they are protected...

Comment: I guess I'll use two pushbuttons, because I think it will make my job easier.

Comment: Those protected members you mention are signals.

Comment: I would just use setCurrentIndex(1) where you have currentIndex(1). Although I am a little confused with your connect statements.

Comment: Well, i resolved the problem using a pushbutton for each type, and using the singal clicked();